# Correct way to define k8s-user-startup-script

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This is like a follow-up question of: [Recommended way to persistently change kube-env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138499/recommended-way-to-persistently-change-kube-env-variables)

I was playing around with the possibility to define a *k8s-user-startup-script* for GKE instances (I want to install additional software to each node).

Adding  *k8s-user-startup-script* to an Instance Group Template "Custom Metadata" works, but that is overwritten by `gcloud container clusters upgrade` which creates a new Instance Template without "inheriting" the additional *k8s-user-startup-script* Metadata from the current template.

I've also tried to add a *k8s-user-startup-script* to the project metadata (I thought that would be inherited by all instances of my project like described  [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata?hl=en_US#projectwide)) but that is not taken into account.

What is the correct way to define a *k8s-user-startup-script* that persists cluster upgrades?
Or, more general, what is the desired way to customize the GKE nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Container Engine doesn't support custom startup scripts for nodes.

As I mentioned in [Recommended way to persistently change kube-env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138499/recommended-way-to-persistently-change-kube-env-variables) you can use a DaemonSet to customize your nodes. A DaemonSet running in privileged mode can do pretty much anything that you could do with a startup script, with the caveat that it is done slightly later in the node bring-up lifecycle. Since a DaemonSet will run on all nodes in your cluster, it will be automatically applied to any new nodes that join (via cluster resize) and because it is a Kubernetes API object, it will be persisted across OS upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Will go for a privileged/hostNetwork DaemonSet than.

Comment: See https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/startup-script for an example of how to do this with a DaemonSet.

Comment: But how to use it to configure kernel parameters before app becomes up? Like:
```
echo 1024 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Comment: Deploy the daemonset to your cluster before deploying the app? Or if you really need to deploy them concurrently you could have your app monitor the file and wait to launch until it has the correct value (via a simple shell wrapper in the dockerfile).

Comment: Note: This does not work if you need to modify your your network config to be able to pull the images required to run the daemonset in the first place :(

Comment: @ffledgling - What network settings do you need to modify? Where is your container image stored?